# gsub and awk to remove the first two underscores from the string "abc_xyz_def_aaa" and abc_def_zyz"

Tags: regex

My strings are like

```
abc_def_xyz and 
abc-def_ghj_fff
```

I want to extract only `xyz and` `ghj_fff` from strings

Comment: This regex should work, not sure about gsub and awk.
\w+?_\w+?_(.*?)\b

Comment: Any feedback on the two answers you received ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find

```
([^_\s]+_){2}
```

and replace with a blank string

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you are looking for?

```
awk -F 'def_' '{print $2}' file
xyz and 
ghj_fff
```